# Calculate inverse proportion from 3 points

Tags: c#, math, graph, curve-fitting

I apologize if this has already been asked - I'm not certain of the right terms to use here, so if it has, hopefully it will help others like me find whatever this gets marked as a dupe of.

I'm looking to create a formula for a curve in code (C# or Javascript ideally) from 3 points - the formula should be of the form y = a/(t+b) + c where t is time - the horizontal axis - and y is the vertical axis. Obviously a, b, and c are just there for graph fit.

How would I go about this? Is there an existing library I should be using?

The source data has a lot more than 3 data points available, I'm just looking for the simplest way to fit a 1/x curve to the data - so if for example 4 points are required for accuracy that's easy to provide as input.

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to look for the mathematic method and then code it?

Comment: If by mathematic method you mean other potential formulas like a cubic - I'm aware of several ways to apply cubic curves to sets of points, but this data is fundamentally 1/x shaped in general - I just need to work each data set back to this general formula.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini Are you saying that you want to fit this specific form of equation to your data and optimise for a,b, and c or are you just using this to illustrate the shape of your data?

Comment: Also by "fit" are you referring to least-squares approximation, or are you looking for a curve that is coincident with your points?

Comment: A curve that is coincident with the input points is fine. It's simply used to illustrate the shape of the data, and to roughly infer places where data may be missing in a given set.

Comment: Maybe you can get a decent algorithm or procedure from http://math.stackexchange.com/ then you can implement in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to fit a function of the form

```
    y(t) = a/(t + b) + c
```

to a set of data points you are faced with a nonlinear least-squares problem for which you can use Gauss-Newton or Levenberg-Marquardt methods. However, there is an old algorithm that goes by the name of `Loeb's algorithm` that can be used to generate good (but not best - it can be shown that it will not converge to the best approximation) approximations when your approximation is a ratio of polynomials. It works by linearising the least-squares problem and results in an iterative least-squares solution (although in practice you will get good results with a single iteration). I studied this algorithm for my doctorate and I would strongly recommend it for any practical problem in which you want to approximate data points using a polynomial ratio (of which your case is very simple example).

The downside is that this algorithm is very old and you may struggle to find decent documentation of it. If you can it is no more complicated to implement than a standard linear least-squares approximation. If you get no better answer here to your problem, consider googling for it. If you cant find and decent information, let me know and I will upload my thesis to my website (contains implementation details of the method) and you can download it.

As I say you may get a far simpler answer here but if not it will certainly be an option open to you.